# How to increase the space between the fields in VerticalFieldManager

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-storm

I am adding three CustomButtons in verticalFieldManager, but there is no spacing between the buttons. all are coming one after the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the method `setPadding(int top, int right, int bottom, int left)`

Answer (score 0):

you can also do it by using `Field.setMargin (int Top, int Right, int Bottom, int Left)` method. You may [find articles on this forum](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/bd-p/java_dev) debating if undocumented functions should be used or not but `setMargin()` has even been used in RIM's own examples so I doubt there is any problem with using it.